# ¿Se pueden poner coordenadas en un tabla de ajedrez caballo?

Tags: python, bucle-for, matrices

Hola Buenas tengo un programa que me hace el recorrido de caballo de caballo en la posicion 0,0 pero si intento poner otras coordendas ya sea en la funcion knightTour se Tarda o me parece un error y si le pongo valores usando la funcion input int igual se tarda algo o me arroja error lo detuve con la funcion de import os ya que al ejecutar la aplicacion me hace un ciclo cuando pongo un valor mas garnde que 6 ahorita esta en 8(N=8). Me podrían ayudar si puedo usar este método u otro método para poner las coordenadas:

```
 from ast import main
 import os
 # Las siguientes listas detallan los ocho movimientos posibles para un caballo.
 # No cambie la secuencia de las listas a continuación
 Valor1 = int(input("Ingrese la fila--> "))
 Valor2 = int(input("Ingrese la columna--> "))
 row = [2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2, 2]
 col = [1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1]


 # Comprueba si `(x, y)` son coordenadas de tablero de ajedrez válidas.
 # Tenga en cuenta que un caballo no puede salir del tablero
 def isValid(x, y):
   return not (x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= N or y >= N)


 # Función recursivo para realizar el recorrido del caballo mediante backtracking
 def knightTour(visited, x, y, pos):

 # marcar la plaza actual como visitada
 visited[x][y] = pos

 # si se visitan todos los cuadrados, imprime la solución
 if pos >= N * N:
     for r in visited:
         print(r)
     print()
     os.system("pause")
     #break
     # retroceder antes de regresar
     visited[x][y] = 0
     return

# verifica los ocho movimientos posibles para un caballo
# y recurren por cada movimiento válido
for k in range(8):

    # obtiene la nueva posición del caballo de la actual
    # Posición # en el tablero de ajedrez
    newX = x + row[k]
    newY = y + col[k]

    # si la nueva posición es válida y aún no visitada
    if isValid(newX, newY) and visited[newX][newY] == 0:
        knightTour(visited, newX, newY, pos + 1)

# retroceder desde el cuadro actual y eliminarlo de la ruta actual
visited[x][y] = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':

# Tablero de ajedrez # `N × N`
N = 5

# visitado tiene dos propósitos:
# 1. Realiza un seguimiento de las casillas involucradas en el recorrido del caballo.
# 2. Almacena el orden de visita de las plazas.
visited = [[0 for x in range(N)] for y in range(N)]
pos = 1

# iniciar el recorrido del caballero desde la plaza de la esquina `(0, 0)`
knightTour(visited, 0, 0, pos)
```

Comment: yo hice un juego parecido pero use tkinter y pygame te recomiendo que uses esas librerias tkinter te va a dar un movimiento mas exacto sobre el tablero y pygame es como el diseño de

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque es duplicada de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/564464/crear-una-lista-de-indices-de-los-vecinos-de-un-elemento-de-una-matriz